# Hyperledger Composer - Queries not registered

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am using `hyperledger` composer 1.1 version.

Queries in queries.qry file not getting registered when running composer-rest-server. I have tried upgrading bna file also, but the issue still exists.

But when creating the sample using yo generator, its working fine, after merging our sample code into it, getting some connectivity issues. getting "participant does not have read access to resource `sample.bna` file.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is the process that should work:

1. Create the file with the **exact name** `queries.qry` and make sure it is **in the root folder of the project** (same folder as package.json and permissions.acl, not any sub folder)
2. Edit the package.json and update the version number for your BNA
3. Create a new .bna file with `composer archive create`
4. Run the command to install the new bna version on the peers `composer network install`
5. Run the command to upgrade the running version of the network on the Peers `composer network upgrade`  (Note that this will create a new chaincode docker container for the new version of the network.)
6. Stop the REST server - start the REST server so that it can *discover* the new end points for the network.